# Android: how to make a drawn shape move & how to draw just part of a shape like a 3/4 solid circle

Tags: android, android-animation

Animation:

All the animations on the Android books I read are made on an existing image. They load an image on the SD card and use animation functions (like alpha, scale, translate and rotate) to make it move. However, what if I want to make the shapes I drew move on the screen. For example, I just draw a circle on the screen and want to make it move from left to right. How can I do this?

Painting:

Functions like drawCircle can draw complete geometric shapes but I just want to draw part of a shape, for example, a 3/4 solid circle. How should I do? If I use drawArc, there will be a 'V' recess on the circle and I want it to be flat.

Comment: you can create vector drawable and use animation on them or even create animated vector drawables